# Why linux sys_unlinkat get param dfd/dirfd always -100?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos, kernel, kernel-module

Can't get fd or dirfd from params, they are always be -100.

The kernel module is developed under CentOS 8.3, Linux kernel version 4.18.

The result is **-100**

I am a little confused why this will happen.

The reason why I need dfd is I want to get the absolute path, when input pathname alike "../".

```c
asmlinkage int modified_unlinkat(const struct pt_regs *regs) {
    int result;
    int dfd = (int)regs->di;
    char *tmp = (char*)__get_free_page(256);
    struct file *files = fget(dfd);
    if (!files) {
        conivent_printf("%d", dfd);
        return -EACCES;
    }
    char *path = d_path(&files->f_path, tmp, PAGE_SIZE);
    conivent_printf("%s", path);
    return -EACCESS;
}
```

If anyone could provide help, I will be extremely appreciate.

Comment: "The result is -100" - The result of **what**? The function `modified_unlinkat` returns `-EACCES` in any case (the second one is a typo: `EACCESS`). There are two prints (`conivent_printf`), first of which prints a pointer via `%d` (which is wrong), the second prints string via `%s` (which is correct).

Comment: It's the result of regs->di, thanks.

Comment: I would like to get struct file, and use d_path to get absolute path, but now, the **dfd** is  -100, which is wrong, cause deletetion aciton hasn't taken yet. And I want to know why this dfd is -100, I read some blog, their dfd is also -100, so what's the point of this param if almost all situation is -100? Thank you so much!

Comment: How do you know dfd is -100? Should `conivent_printf("%d", files);` be `conivent_printf("%d", dfd);`? Also, what is `conivent_printf`?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong code, yes, `conivent_printf("%d", files)` is `conivent_printf("%d", dfd)`. `conivent_printf` is just like `printf`.

Comment: It seems that -100 is the value of `#define AT_FDCWD  -100` - macro, which denotes the descriptor of the current directory.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you so much!!! I will check it out tomorrow. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: And is there any good way to get the absolute path? I see some func like mkdir doesn't have fd cause it's not created, how to get theirs absolute path?

Comment: You can look at the existing code unlinkat syscall code (`SYSCALL_DEFINE3(unlinkat, int, dfd, const char __user *, pathname, int, flag)` and `do_unlinkat` and `do_rmdir` in "fs/namei.c") to see how to get the absolute path.